# Google Sheets for loop script 'Improvement Suggestions'

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been working on for loop script for automating the data collection, basically, the objective was, to search 'good morning' in the string 'hello good morning' if found the return category if not then ignore it, so for this I decided to use the formula 'QUERY' and copy/paste append that result to another sheet.

What do you guys suggest? I am just worried just in case the library increases more than 2K rows then this file will take forever to load.

```
function verbatimGen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1 = ss.getSheetByName('verbatim_tester')
  var library = ss.getSheetByName('library')
  var result = ss.getSheetByName('result')
  var queryResult = ss.getSheetByName('query')

  for(var i =0;i<library.getLastRow(); i++){
    var keyword = library.getRange(i+2,1).getValue();
    s1.getRange('E2').setValue(keyword)

    var cCopy = queryResult.getRange(2,1,queryResult.getLastRow(), queryResult.getLastColumn()).getValues();

    result.getRange(result.getLastRow() + 1,1, cCopy.length, cCopy[0].length).setValues(cCopy);
      }
}
```

Thanks guys for the help, here is an example of the tables:

verbatim_tester sheet has a table like this one

| ID | Verbatim |
| --- | --- |
| 1231 | Horrible Service |
| 23453 | Slow and bad |
| 34534 | The fox is not red |

Table Library looks like this:

| Keyword | category |
| --- | --- |
| Horrible | Negative |
| slow and bad | support |
| not red | support |

so the script will iterate in range of Library 'A2:A' and paste each value at the time in cell 'E2' which feeds this formula in 'query sheet',

```
=query(verbatim_tester!A1:B,"Select * where LOWER(B) contains LOWER('"&verbatim_tester!E2&"')")
```

The query sheet has a table that looks like this one:

| Query Formula | query space | Keyword | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| query results | query results | =verbatim_tester!$E$2 | =verbatim_tester!$F$2 |
| query results | query results | =IF(LEN(B3)>0,$C$2,"") | =IF(LEN(B3)>0,$D$2,"") |

The script will copy the entire range and paste append each results into result sheet and the final output looks like this

| ID | Verbatim | Keyword | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1231 | Horrible service | horrible | negative |
| 23453 | Slow and Bad | Slow and bad | support |
| 34534 | the fox is not red | not red | support |

Comment: Without you data it's hard to  offers alternatives.  These days I tend to lean heavily with textFinder.

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as [**text table**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/)(NOT as IMAGE) to the question. Adding such [md tables](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Don't use loops to read/write single cell values. Instead use batch operations (we already have a lot of questions about this. You might also read about this in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices

Comment: Whenever possible, include a minimal example of the data, so it can be easier to work or find alternatives. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way

Comment: Thanks guys I'm taking a look at all the suggestions, I also added already some text tables as example